# Trouble with loader.close

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, loader

Can anybody explain, why loader.close didn't work?
Btw i know about loading files from server thing.

```
for (var p:Number = 0; p < itemsOnPage; p++) 
{
    if (itterationStep != SqlRec.itemsArray.length) 
    {
        thumbImgLoader = new Loader();
        var imgName:String = SqlRec.itemsArray[itterationStep]["img"];
        thumbImgLoader.load(new URLRequest(GetXMLprefs.thumbsPath + imgName));
        thumbLoadersArray.push(thumbImgLoader);
        ...
    }
}

/////

if (ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray) 
{
    if(ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray.length; i++) 
        {
            try 
            {
                var obj:Loader = new Loader();
                obj = ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray[i];
                obj.close();
                trace(">> "+obj.close);
            }catch (err:Error) 
            {
                trace(err)
            }
        }
        ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray.splice(0, ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: When did you call `obj.close();`? May be loading is already completed? and why `var obj:Loader = new Loader();` directly before `obj = ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray[i];`?

Comment: i'm using "try" when calling close() because i didn't know was loading already completed or not. But I can tell it for sure because there is 800 images and it can't be completed so fast.
problem is, i can't load new images before all loaders load was completed.
When i click button1 it loads 800 images, before all images was loaded i click button2 and it's supposed to load another 200 images in the same place but it freezes for some time like it's waiting for load complete...
obj:Loader = new Loader(); is just a try
it can be like:
ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray[i].close();

Comment: You should have a look at [BuldLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/). Makes loading of this huge amount of images much more comfortable.

Comment: Seriously loading 800 images? You really need to make it load on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting anything out of the trace?

Flash has an internal limit with how many simultaneous loads it can do at once. You're loading 800 images in a loop, which means that the first ~780 or so will be overridden by the last 20 or so. The max I ever load at once is around 10 (I think [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) has something similar). If you want to load in 800 images, use the array to keep track of what's loading in. Something like:

```
private var m_imagesLoaded:int = 0;
private var m_toLoad:Array = null;

private function _init():void
{
    // create your array and set the first 10 or so loading
    this.m_toLoad = new Array( 800 );
    ...
}

private function _onImageLoad( e:Event ):void
{
    // load the next one in the list
    this.m_imagesLoaded++;
    this.m_toLoad[this.m_imagesLoaded].load();

    // do whatever else
}
```

As for `close()`, it "[Cancels a load() method operation that is currently in progress for the Loader instance](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#close%28%29)." If there's no `load()` going on in the `Loader`, then nothing's probably going to happen.

*P.S.: in your `try` statement, you're creating a new `Loader` everytime, before assigning it to something else. Just change it to*

```
var obj:Loader = ItemsBuilder.thumbLoadersArray[i];
```